# When will the classification of a property of a group be complete

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying pronormal Hall $\pi$-subgroups of a finite group $G$

All Hall $\pi$-subgroups of a finite solvable groups are known to be pronormal as this follows from Hall's theorem

Recently, it has been proven that Hall $\pi$-subgroups of finite simple groups are pronormal.

Can we then say that in general that Hall $\pi$-subgroups of a finite group $G$ are pronormal?

I am posing this question as I want to investigate pronormality of Hall $\pi$-subgroups of finite almost simple groups

Comment: So far, this is studied for certain classes of groups, e.g., Hall subgroups of finite solvable groups are pronormal, and Hall subgroups of finite simple groups are paranormal. Hence it seems not to be the case that one knows this "in general".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether it is true for almost simple groups, but it is not true in general.

For $\pi = \{2,3\}$, ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ has two non-conjugate Hall $\pi$-subgroups of order $24$, and we can use that to construct a counterexample.

Let $G = {\rm PSL}(2,7) \wr C_5$ be the wreath product of ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ and a cyclic group of order $5$. Then $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(2,7)^5$, which has $2^5$ conjugacy classes of Hall $\pi$-subgroups. They are also Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$, but $G$ has only $8$ such classes.

So if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$ that are conjugate in $G$ but not in $N$, then they are not conjugate in $\langle H_1,H_2 \rangle \le N$.

Comment: So one would only need to consider finite almost simple groups of even order since any group of odd order is solvable.

Comment: Yes. By the classification of finite simple groups, the finite almost simple groups are in a sense "known". So it means that you need to learn something about the automorphisms of the finite simple groups. The majority of these are groups of Lie type, and the automorphism group is generated by diagonal, field and graph automorphisms.